# Synchronize specific files to repo

Tags: git, synchronization

I'm quite new to git so it's probably a very naive question.
I have a few files that are quite important to me, and that I'd like to synchronize online.

Here is what I can't figure out how to do:

- There is like one single file out of each specific folder.
- I'd like not to mess up with my local folder's structure.

It may be clearer with a picture. Is this possible?
[image]
Thanks!

Comment: It's possible but it may not be the best approach. You would have to initialize a Git repository in root, add only those specific files and ignore all others.

Comment: If the files are not related to each other it would be better to have separate repositories in each subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

git by default follow symlink, so you can:

```sh
# assuming you want to save the repo in ~/myrepo and assuming the files that you want to track is in ~/myroot
mkdir ~/myrepo
cd ~/myrepo
git init

# make symlink for file a1
ln -s ~/myroot/dir_a/file_a1 ~/myrepo/file_a1

# make symlink for whole directory b
ln -s ~/myroot/dir_b ~/myrepo/dir_b

# make symlink for file c1 and c2
ln -s ~/myroot/dir_c/file_c1 ~/myrepo/file_c1
ln -s ~/myroot/dir_c/file_c2 ~/myrepo/file_c2

git add .
git commit -m 'msg here'
```

this way, you can edit file in `~/myroot` and the changes are automatically reflected in your repo (since it's just symlink)